# How to make an opacity background under Drawer Side with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm doing a drawer navigation with design, but I don't know how to custom an opacity background under it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To apply blur (like this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_filter&preval=blur(5px)) you need to use a third party lib since React Native doesn't support it by default. You can check if this one handles exactly what you need https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur

By the print screen you posted, however, it looks like you want to make a darken background when your menu is activated. To do so, you can apply `backgroundColor` style to your main component with some value like `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)`. Or you can also have a component over your content that's displayed when your menu is activated. Or your menu container can hold the `backgroundColor` since the menu itself won't fit the whole screen (I think it's the best option).

Example:

`<View style={{ backgroundColor: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), flex: 1 }}>
  <Menu>
    ...
  </Menu>
</View>`

Consider the code above just as an expression of the idea. You must apply the correct styles to make it

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by using `overlayColor` prop in Drawer Navigator.

```
 <Drawer.Navigator
    overlayColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    headerMode="none">
    <Drawer.Screen name={ROUTES.HOME} component={HomeStack} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
```

See this link for more information on the customization of the drawer. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent